# How do I use my own my.cnf/mysqld.cnf inside a MYSQL docker-compose?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I want to use my own configuration file to better utilize my server and to set mysql to be case insensitive. This is the path to my cnf file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.

I assumed you would add it the same way you add `/var/lib/mysql` but it doesn't do anything. I also tried:

```
volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./data/db/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf.
```

This is my docker-compose:

```
   version: '3.3'
    services:
      db:
        image: mysql:latest
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - db:/var/lib/mysql
          # focus on this
          - db:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
        env_file: ./.env
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${password}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${database}
            MYSQL_USER: ${user}
            MYSQL_ROOT_USER: ${user}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${password}
            #MYSQL_HOST: ${password}
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
        ports:
          - ${db_port}:${db_port}
        cap_add:
          - SYS_NICE
      app:
        # ...
        depends_on:
          - db
    volumes: 
      db:
```

How can I put my own cnf into a docker mysql container?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs on docker hub, you have to create the volume with the parent folder:
`/my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d`

Where `/my/custom` contains the config files.

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This does add some commands but the main cofigurations that I would like to change don't apply/ give out an error when they shouldn't.